# Dynamic Google Analytics segments in Google Data Studio

Tags: google-analytics, analytics, looker-studio

We want to embed a Google Data Studio dashboard in the admin side of our application, which
is installed on our customers' websites.

Customers can login to the admin and see the data linked to their account, such as analytics.

The Google Data Studio dashboard includes connectors to our database and to Google Analytics.

Data from Google Analytics must be filtered per customer, with a segment that includes data
from their website only.

How to dynamically add a Google Analytics segment to our dashboard ?

I found that it is possible to pass parameters in the embed link, but how to use
these parameters to filter Google Analytics data dynamically ?

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It doesn't seem possible to do that unfortunately. We ended up creating Data Studio sheets manually and adding the right parameters for major customers.
We are moving to a custom data dashboard linked to the Google Analytics API (not using Data Studio).